# How to cut iOS8 assets from a PSD designed at 1242px by 2208px

Tags: ios, photoshop

The designers on a project I am responsible for developing (one of my first iOS projects) designed the app using a Photoshop canvas set at 1242x2208 pixels, which is the number of pixels that the iPhone 6+ uses. I've scoured the internet and am just getting more and more confused by all the conversions for 1x, 2x, 3x and to further the confusion, apple downsizes to 1080x1920.

Anyways, how do I cut the assets correctly for @1x, @2x, @3x? When I crop the element I want, I save it out at 3x. But what do I divide by to get the 2x and 1x versions?

Here's secondary question and a hypothetical situation: There is a button that is designed to be the full width of the screen in portrait, so the designer made it 1242x100. If I save it out at 3x, then scale it down for 2 and 1x, will this button fit all the different screen sizes all the way down to iPhone 4/4s, which has a smaller pixel dimension and different aspect ratio?

Confused, any help appreciated!

Comment: If you want to do it right, request the designs for each of the supported device types. Otherwise you'll have to adopt the design you have for smaller screens and you seem to have problems even before you started. Image scaling is pretty straightforward, the real question is whether you want to use the same image with different scales on all devices. If you do then it's easy, and if you don't then your question doesn't apply. Hope it cleared out a few things.

Comment: The assumption was that the app could be build at the largest size (iPhone 6+) and scale all the day down to iPhone 4s. Since all the phones except iPhone 4s is 16:9 aspect ratio, I guess everyone assumed a single large PSD would be fine. Is this not the case?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be fine for you, does it ?

Comment: Ah what I had to do was delete the Launch Image files and a couple other things. Then I just designed it for iPhone 5 size and iOS automatically scaled up iPhone 5 layout to iPhone 6+ (not using native resolution, but it still used to 3x images). I just used the 320 x 568 pts coordinate system in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: 
If you original artwork is 960px by 1704px, just save you image including "@3x"

```
image@3x.png   // (960  x 1704)
```

Then you have to resize it to 640x1136 and save including "2x"

```
image@2x.png   // (640x1136)
```

And then you have to resize it to 320x568 and save as 1x

```
image.png      // (320x568)
```

Comment: Thanks! The original artwork however was at 1242x2208. Is that not the 3x resolution? This link http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified seems to imply that the 3 resizes would need to be: 1242x2208, 750x1334, and 320x480/568 (depending on iPhone 4 or 5). Where did your numbers for 2x and 3x come from?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the Retina sizes are confusing, but this is what auto resize is used for in Xcode.

But The API which Apple give us, chooses the @3, @2 and 1 sizes by itself. There isn't anything that the developer/designer needs to do but provide all three images. An example is:

ObjC:

```
+ (NSImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name]
```

Swift:

```
init?(named name: String) -> NSImage
```

Would just use the name of the image without the @ etc... So, myImageName@3x.png myImageName@2x.png myImageName.png would just be referred to as "myImageName"

The API handles the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. What I did was, after cutting all images for iPhone 6+(@3x), I just resized the PSD to iPhone 5's width which is 640px, (height would be 1138 px if you keep aspect ratio) and cut @2x images. For the 1x images, again resized to 320px width.

Just, iPhone 6+, iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 have almost same aspect ratio.

Good Luck!